# How many draw calls is necessary to draw a triangle fan in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw a triangle fan. I wonder if it takes 1 draw call or more. I don't think this is important, but I draw with OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` primitive type. So you can draw a triangle fan with a single draw call:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, ...);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, ...);
```

The first vertex defines the "origin" of the fan. If you have `n` vertices for a triangle fan, there will be `n - 2` triangles drawn with the following vertices:

```
0, 1, 2
0, 2, 3
0, 3, 4
...
0, n - 2, n - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

From user point of view, you need just 1 draw call.

Internall for GPU or software renderer, this is implementation dependent whether the a particular implementation would take 1 or more draw calls.

On all GPUs known to me, we prepare just 1 draw stream which is sent to GPU and GPU draws it in 1 burst.